# Laravel: Uri tests fail whenever models are being queried in controllers, but not when the response is just a view

Tags: laravel, testing

My test is pretty simple, I just want to know if the url returns a 200 ok status.

```
public function test_categories_page_is_accessible()
{
        $response = $this->get(route('category.index'));
        $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

But for some reason this fails. However, when I remove model queries in the controller, and just return a view the test passes. The page is accessible in the browser without any problem whatsoever.

```
// CategoryController.php

// Fails
public function index()
{
    $models = Category::all();

    return view('category-index', [
        'categories' => $models,
    ]);
}


// Fails
public function index()
{
    $models = Category::all();

    return view('category-index', [
        'categories' => [],
    ]);
}


// Passes
public function index()
{
    // $models = Category::all();

    return view('category-index', [
        'categories' => [],
    ]);
}
```

I have no idea why this is and can't find anything similar on SO.

Comment: Could you log the error? Could it be possible that you imported the wrong Category model class?

Comment: The Category model is correct. However, your reply triggered me to look in the logs and that tells me that 'categories table does not exist' (it does). Should I set a some overlooked DB setting somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Completely overlooked the settings in phpunit.xml. Changed the DB_CONNECTION and DB_DATABASE and works beautifully now.